# Excel no puede abrir el archivo 'Prueba.xlsx' porque el formato o la extensión de éste no son válidos

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hace un par de días todo funcionaba con normalidad (Ya mas de un año) pero hace 2 días cuando descargo una base de datos generados con PHP me sale el error que coloque en el titulo de esta pregunta, sera algo que ver con que el servidor hizo alguna actualización con la versión de PHP o no tienen nada que ver?

Comment: ¿Podrías facilitarnos el archivo `prueba.xlsx` para inspeccionar su formato interno? Tiene toda la pinta que éste contiene mensajes de advertencia y/o error lanzados por PHP que han sido agregados a su contenido.

Comment: Tienes PHPExcel copiado en tu proyecto o lo instalas con Composer?